# Botaniq plugin crash on eevee with OCIO Aces

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I installed OCIO Aces on Blender version 3.6.5, when I add an asset from Botaniq by Polygoniq the viewport render using **Eevee always crashes**, but somehow **Cycles works perfectly fine**

Comment: What OCIO configuration did you install? Where did you get it from?

Comment: ...I would recommend contacting the creator of the add-on with this question.